# mySQL case when - what if the conditions are not mutually exclusive?

Tags: mysql, sql, case

I have a question: for Case When statement in SQL/MYsql, what if the conditions are not mutually exclusive?
case when condition1 then x1
when condition2 then x2
when condition3 then x3 end as result

if both condition 1 and 2 are true, which one is the result that is returned? x1 or x2?

Comment: the first true statement is returned.

Answer (score 5):

The first one. The conditions will be evaluated in order and only the first true one will be returned

Comment: If the case clause is in the join (instead of the select), both results will be returned.